# Problema de permissão ao tentar inserir uma imagem em um diretório com PHP

Tags: php

Estou tendo problemas em fazer um upload de uma imagem em um diretório, me parece que não tenho permissão de escrita. Já adicionei `chmod 775` para a pasta e nada, o que poderia ser?

Tenho meu arquivo de inserção dessa forma:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Teste de upload</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="fileUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
   </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['fileUpload']))
   {
      date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão

      $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['fileUpload']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
      $new_name = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . $ext; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
      $dir = './'; //Diretório para uploads

      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo
   }
?>
```

Os erros que estão acontecendo são esses:
[image: Erro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que estava acontecendo é que não estava sendo encontrado o diretório, então alterei o seguinte trecho no código:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'], "../uploaded/".$new_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

A pastas precisam conter permissão para escrita do servidor WEB, provavelmente você não deu tais permissões.

Mesmo que tenha dado 755 o usuário do apache provavelmente não esteja no grupo da pasta, então coloque o grupo _www para essa pasta.

Pelo caminho acredito que esteja usando o MAC, então abra seu terminal (command+espaço escreva term e de enter).

Após isso rode os dois comando abaixo no terminal para dar as permissões necessárias na pasta.

```
sudo chown andremartins:_www /Users/andremartins/developer/workspaces -R
sudo chmod 755 /Users/andremartins/developer/workspaces -R
```

Stackoverflow English Answer: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001881/correct-owner-group-permissions-for-apache-2-site-files-folders-under-mac-os-x**